# Console open in Safari Devtools, but console.log('hello') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, safari

I use Chrome Devtools constantly, but Safari is new to me.

I'm trying to  use Safari 7 to debug a Safari specific site issue, but I cannot make console.log work. The following [very basic jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezAa3/) fails on Safari:

```
console.log('hello')
```

As pictured, nothing appears in the 'console' UI.

Safari has lots of ...things.. for me to click on. Do I need to do something to make the console work?

[image]

Comment: Try with a function...wait...so when you run that code doesnt show anything on the console??

Comment: Yes. Check the jsfiddle provided.

Comment: I see the word `hello` in the console on Safari 7.0 (9537.71).

Comment: Works for me as well, maybe refresh the page with the console open?

Comment: @all Refreshing the page with the console open doesn't log anything. At the '>' prompt, typing "console.log('test')" seems to pause on pressing enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing the Safari process in Activity Monitor didn't fix it, but rebooting OS X did.

*sigh*

Comment: Thanks a LOT for this little advice. I wasn't thinking it would be something like this. Time saved.

Answer (score 1):

To [Apple](http://www.apple.com/safari/) in case they are seeing this:

It's really unfortunate, how easily the `console.log` gets pushed off its feet in Safari 7 (9537.71). All it takes is i.e. misspelling `Math.pow2` (there is no such function in the Math library). Refreshes, `console.log` no longer responds. On this occasion, restarting Safari brought it back.

Please, make a fix.